# Blend JOptionpane code with jFrame code

Tags: java, swing, awt

My partner and I have been working on seperate parts of a project and now we would like to put them together, but we're having trouble.  He wrote his part of the code for jOptionpane but the finished project will use jFrame.

This particular part of the code compiles, but it doesn't write anything to the files, where it works in the jOptionpane version. Basically we want to read from the textfields and write them to the .txt files. I'm aware there may be slight differences when using a unix based os but we aren't having success on windows either. I've tried to emulate other answers from this site but I'm not having any luck.  Any hints or suggestions?

```
public void jTextField1ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent te)               
{             
    String user,usersPass;
    FileWriter fw;
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;



    if (te.getSource() == jTextField1)

    {

        user = jTextField1.getText();

    }
        else if (te.getSource() == jTextField2)

            {

                usersPass = jTextField2.getText();

             }


                try
                   {
                       ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(100);
                       ArrayList<String> passwords = new ArrayList<String>(100);



                       File userNames = new File("Username.txt");
                       Scanner users = new Scanner(userNames);
                       File userPass = new File("Passwords.txt");
                       Scanner pass = new Scanner(userPass);



                       // FileWriter fw;
                       //  FileReader fr;
                       fw = new FileWriter("Macintosh  Hd/Users/smooth4prez/Desktop/Project/Username.txt");
                       fr = new FileReader("Macintosh Hd/Users/smooth4prez/Desktop/Project/Passwords.txt");
                       writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                       reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
                   }
                   catch(FileNotFoundException E)
                       {
                           E.printStackTrace();
                       }
                               catch(IOException e)
                                   {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                                   }

}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {

        if (evt.getSource() == jButton1)

            {
                dispose ();

                new SignIn().setVisible(true);

            }

}
```

Here is the jOptionpane version that we are trying to rework.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class LoginTest implements Serializable

{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  


 public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotSerializableException
 {
    Username();
 }
 public static void Username()throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
 {
   File userNames = new File("Username.txt");
    Scanner users = new Scanner(userNames);
    File userPass = new File("Passwords.txt");
    Scanner pass = new Scanner(userPass);

    FileWriter fWriteUser = new FileWriter("Username.txt", true);
   PrintWriter outUser = new PrintWriter(fWriteUser);
    FileWriter fWritePass = new FileWriter("Passwords.txt", true);
   PrintWriter outPass = new PrintWriter(fWritePass);       

    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(100);
  ArrayList<String> passwords = new ArrayList<String>(100);

    int userCount = 0;

    while(users.hasNext())
    {
        String oldName = users.nextLine();
        nameList.add(oldName);
        userCount = userCount + 1;
    }
    while(pass.hasNext())
    {
        String oldPass = pass.nextLine();
        passwords.add(oldPass);
    }

    String strNumUsers = "";

    strNumUsers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many users would you like to register?");

    int numUsers = Integer.parseInt(strNumUsers);

    int newCount = userCount + 1;

   for(int j = 0;j < numUsers;j++)
    {

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the username");

        for(int i = 0;i < nameList.size();i++)
        {
            if(username.equals(nameList.get(i)))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That username is already taken");
                username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the username");

                i = 0;
            }
        }

        nameList.add(username);              

        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter password");
       passwords.add(password);

        File dir = new File("Inbox" + newCount); 
        dir.mkdir();
        File folder = new File("Inbox" + newCount);

        File m;
        m = new File("Macintosh Hd/Users/smooth4prez/Desktop/Project3/Inbox" + newCount + "/messages.txt");
        m.createNewFile();

        File n;
        n = new File("Macintosh Hd/Users/smooth4prez/Desktop/Project3/Inbox" + newCount + "/outbox.txt");
        n.createNewFile();

        newCount = newCount + 1;
   }

    for(int k = userCount;k < nameList.size();k++)
    {
        outUser.println(nameList.get(k));
        outPass.println(passwords.get(k));
    }
    outUser.close();
    outPass.close();

    String signInUserName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username to sign in");

    for(int i = 0;i < nameList.size();i++)
    {
        if(signInUserName.equals(nameList.get(i)))
        {

            String signInPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your password");
            if(signInPassword.equals(passwords.get(i)))
            {
                String response = "";

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Signed in!");
                i = nameList.size();

                response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to send a message, view messages, or exit?" + 
                "(Please enter send, view, or exit.)");

                /*switch(response.trim())
                {
                case "Send":
                case "send":
                    Messages.MessageTest(nameList, signInUserName);
                    break;
                case "View":
                case "view":
                    Messages.MessageView(nameList, signInUserName);
                    break;
                case "Exit":
                case "exit":
                    break;
                case "":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't enter anything, DIPSHIT!");
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a proper response.");
                    break;
                }*/
                /*
                Save s = new Save();
                testObject Rob = new testObject();
                s.saveMyObject("myfile", Rob);

                //Saving an object with class Save.java
                /*
                Save s = new Save();
                Object myObject = new Object();
                String test = "test";
                myObject = (Object)test;
                s.saveMyObject("myfile", myObject);
                */


                //insert program to search for specific user homepage file
                //if found, load that homepage, if not found, call method to create homepage
                //and save it as a file with the title including the username
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect password");
                i = nameList.size();
            }
        }
        else if(!signInUserName.equals(nameList.get(i)))
        {
            if(i + 1 == nameList.size())
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a valid username");
            }       
        }           
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: Your use of brackets and indentation makes absolutely no sense, please fix it first.

Comment: Sorry. I was fixing that before I even read your comment.  It really didn't paste the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Get the person who wrote it to fix it.  Stop mixing I/O API's without reason :P

Comment: @user2016569 It's still really, really broken. No need to use `{}` without a reason, and indentation should be 4 spaces or a tab (as in the symbol `<tab>`/`\t`. The braces doesn't match either. If the braces match, most editors/IDEs should be able to autoindent it for you.

Comment: That edit improves the formatting of the 1st code, but it is still not entirely correct.  **Do you use an IDE?** Repeat @timss sage advice *"most editors/IDEs should be able to autoindent it for you."*  most also have a hot key to format the entire source file.

Comment: Your code didn't paste the way you want to because it sometimes has tabs for indentation and other times has spaces. I suggest that you replace all the tabs with an appropriate number (maybe 4?) of spaces to fix the formatting.

Comment: @AndrewThompson An IDE may or may not fix the problem depending on how it deals with the combination of both tabs and spaces used as indentation.

Comment: @Code-Guru  Huh.  I thought Netbeans at least handled it automatically.  I would be surprised if other IDEs *failed* to do so.  Can you name a specific IDE?

Comment: I used jGrasp to write it.  It looks fine in there.

Answer (score 3):

> He wrote his part of the code for jOptionpane but the finished project will use jFrame.

A frame might well pop dialogs or option panes as required.  One good example I see in that (horridly formatted) code above is to query the user for information.  The alternative if it were in a frame would be to have an input field (e.g. `JTextField`) with an action listener attached.  It will be acted on when the user types something and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>

In the latter case, you will probably need multiple components which need to be laid out using a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), or a combination of layout managers.

The parts of the code that use a message type option pane might be replaced with a `JLabel` at an appropriate place in the GUI, though some of those messages actually seem to be things that *should* appear in a free floating option pane.  YMMV.

Comment: The code is already using a jTextField with a listener attached.

Comment: There is only so much of that I could read before I went cross-eyed.  Please, *please,* ***please*** heed the advice about using a consistent & logical indent for the code blocks and code statements.

Comment: It's the very first line.  Are you speaking about the top portion of code or the bottom?

Comment: *"It's the very first line."* D'Oh!  I was referring to the bottom code (the option pane part).  Since every desktop app. (just about) should have a `JFrame`, your part of the code was irrelevant.  I needed to see how the option panes were used.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm being mocked or not.  You want me to reformat the bottom section of code?

Comment: (shrugs)  OK the latter code was not *that* bad..  It was really the higgledy-piggledy indentation on the opening field declarations that drew my eye - 1st impressions count for a lot.  The bracket indentation is relatively easy to follow.